# Make the dock show only the apps running in the current space

Tags: macos, dock, spaces

I'd like to have multiple spaces for different purposes, for example, one for work, and one for entertainment. However, I found out that in mac, even if you have different spaces in which different kinds of apps are running, the apps in the dock are just lumped together from all those spaces and look messy. It only seems sensible to me that boundaries are drawn between different spaces or else it's easy to be distracted by irrelevant things.

Also, I cannot use the default app switcher as it also cannot show the apps running in the current space only, plus the app order is constantly changing, and holding the shortcut key is simply tiring.

So, is there anything I can do to show only the apps running in the current space in the dock? Or maybe not necessarily the dock, but any kind of app switcher interface where I can switch between apps running in the current space. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend HyperSwitch.app

Comment: I've tried a bunch of apps and found out that sidebar from the app Contexts with some tweaking can be very close to what I want for the dock.